# Auto updating object (ActiveRecord) data after save() in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2.
when I save ActiveRecord object that has autogenerated field date:

```
$obj = new Something();
$obj->name = 'abc';
// $obj->date.... not specified but generates by db engine
$obj->save();
```

Is it possible to get $obj->date without reinitializing object like

```
$obj = Something::findOne($obj->id);
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ActiveRecord::refresh()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#refresh%28%29-detail) which

> Repopulates this active record with the latest data.